# unable to retrieve value from spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

This is a very basic issue.

It is that, I have a basic Spinner implemented with a listener as below:

```
Spinner sensModeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SensorModeSpinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sensModeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sensorMode_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
sensModeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sensModeSpinner.setAdapter(sensModeAdapter);

sensModeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        sMode = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You need to select atleast one mode!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});


Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sensorMode = " + sMode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The issue is the `sMode` variable result is NOT appearing in the Toast message(value is NULL) where as it works fine within the `OnItemSelected` method.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are setting the sMode variable inside onItemSelected, the Toast is executed before that.

Comment: Any directions as of how to fix this? A sample would be great!

Comment: You can place the toast inside onItemSelected after the sMode is set. If you can tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve with the Toast, I can guide you better.

Comment: is sMode initliazed with anything ?

Comment: Thanks! Well, I actually want to get the value of sMode to do some other operations. This Toast message is just a way of testing whether it is working or not outside the Listener class.

Comment: Kartik, it doesn't matter. I want a value selected out of the spinner list after it has been selected to perform some operations.

Comment: When you say "it has been selected" you mean when an item is selected in the spinner, you want to perform some operation. Is that correct?

Comment: Then you can place the call to that operation/function inside onItemSelected after you set sMode

Comment: That is because the code outside is executed inline. The code inside the onItemSelected is executed only when you select an item in the Spinner. So what is happening is that the Toast is executed before you actually select any item in the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

you are executing the `Toast.show();` method before the sMode value could be set, instead place this in `onItemSelected()` after setting sMode value, change your code to following:

```
Spinner sensModeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SensorModeSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sensModeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sensorMode_array,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    sensModeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sensModeSpinner.setAdapter(sensModeAdapter);

    sensModeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
            sMode = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sensorMode = " + sMode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "You need to select atleast one mode!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want the value of sMode outside the inner class!

Comment: you can use, but only where you need it, if you need on some other event, then place the Toast on that event. Please note existing code, will execute this Toast.show method, just after it set listener on the spinner, where no item has been selected yet.

Comment: To repeat what I said above, This Toast message is just a way of testing to see if sMode value is appearing or not. I'm not using the Toast class at all!

Comment: test sMode value, in whatever operation you are intended to use. not after setOnItemSelectedListener, you will get value there, if you have selected, any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
    Spinner sensModeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SensorModeSpinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sensModeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sensorMode_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
sensModeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sensModeSpinner.setAdapter(sensModeAdapter);

sensModeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        sMode = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        //CALL_YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You need to select atleast one mode!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, but this code has previously worked for me before and not now!!

Comment: You can read about listeners [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

some time may be it is silly mistake so try this..

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

   // sMode = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

     sMode = parent.getAdapter().getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

}
```